# how to use Apache ignite as backend layer for computation/aggregation of a reporting webapplication

Tags: java, ignite

We have a reporting web application which does the reporting calculation/aggregation in its own JVM thus report generation is slow in terms of performance .  Reporting application is already using cache(in house cache mechanism) data for aggregation .
We are trying to move the existing aggregation layer to Apache ignite to speed up the application and we are trying to find out the following answers in terms of  apache ignite integration with existing web application .

1> How do we send our existing cache data to ignite cluster (application JVM in one server and ignite JVM/node/processes in other remote servers)and have the calculation logic running in the cluster node and finally retrieve  back result from cluster JVM to application JVM for further processing ?

2> is ignite code invocation simple API call which can be designed as ignite service layer and we can use that customized service layer as part of our existing reporting application with in the existing JVM ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use, for example, EJB, I would recommend create Singleton session bean(as it is never passivated) with Ignite client in it. With client node you will connect to Ignite cluster. Here is [documentation about clients and servers](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers).

With this client you're able to do all operations with cluster(put/get data, invoke compute jobs, use services, etc.)

Useful links:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-grid

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid